# Object that can be coerced to either String, Fixnum, or Float?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to define an object that can be coerced to either a String or a Fixnum or a Float? This is for use in a system that collects values and evaluates a restricted set of simple expressions with them.

I tried:

```
class EmptyValue < Numeric
  def to_s; ''; end
  def to_str; ''; end
  def to_i; 0; end
  def to_int; 0; end
  def to_f; 0.0; end
end
```

but this fails for

```
1 + e
TypeError: EmptyValue can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Comment: Assuming `e = EmptyValue.new`, `1 + e` returns `1.0` for me across MRI Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, and 2.0.  Which version of Ruby are you using?  What is `e`?

Comment: I think I hadn't inherited from Numeric at first.

Comment: Why not use `nil` for this? `nil.to_s`, `nil.to_i`, etc. all do The Right Thing. Or do you not want to be calling `6.to_i` and such all the time?

Comment: correct, the expressions are created by end users in a decision table tool. A common source of errors is forgetting to put a value in a column in a row where it is not relevant (i.e., 0 or ''), when that value can be eval'd later.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the error message. When Ruby says `"... can't be coerced ..."`, it actually means `"... will not be coerced automatically; but you should do it manually"`.

Comment: lol, not sure why you think I am misunderstanding that. I think you are misundersting what I mean by "system...that evaluates a restricted set of simple expressions". Unless you're suggesting that this system should parse the expressions and determine where it needs to insert "manual" coercions. In which case it wouldn't really be simple anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done long time ago:

```
class NullObject
  attr_reader :null_object_type, :recorded_messages
  alias ρ recorded_messages
  def initialize( type_of_null_object = nil )
    @null_object_type = type_of_null_object
    @recorded_messages = []
  end
  def null_object? null_type = nil
    null_object_type == null_type
  end
  alias null? null_object?
  def to_a; [] end
  def to_s; "null #{null_object_type}".strip end
  def to_f; 0.0 end
  def to_i; 0 end
  def present?; false end
  def empty?; true end
  def blank?; true end
  def inspect
    "NullObject #{null_object_type}".strip
  end
  def method_missing ß, *aj, &b      # :nodoc:
    @recorded_messages << [ ß, aj, b ]; self
  end
  def respond_to? ß, *aj, &b         # :nodoc:
    true
  end

  protected
  def == other                       # :nodoc:
    null_object_type == other.null_object_type
  end
end # class NullObject

# Strong zero.
# 
ZERO = NullObject.new
ZERO.instance_exec {
  ɪ = self
  singleton_class.class_exec do
    define_method :zero do ɪ end
  end

  def * other; other.class.zero end
  def / other
    self unless other.zero?
    raise ZeroDivisionError, "The divisor is zero! (#{other})"
  end
  def + other; other end
  def - other; -other end
  def coerce other
    return other, other.class.zero
  end
  def zero?; true end
  def to_s; "∅" end
  def inspect; to_s end
  def to_f; 0.0 end
  def to_i; 0 end
  def == other
    z = begin
          other.class.zero
        rescue NoMethodError
          return false
        end
    other == z
  end
}

class << Numeric; def zero; 0.0 end end
class << Integer; def zero; 0 end end
class << Float; def zero; 0.0 end end
class << Rational; def zero; Rational 0, 1 end end
class << Complex; def zero; Complex 0, 0 end end
class << String; def zero; '' end end
class << Array; def zero; [] end end
class << Hash; def zero; {} end end
```

So, now you have `0 + ZERO #=> 0`. I called this "strong zero". But it was a hack. I have a gut feeling, that this is not such a good practice.

Comment: my evaluator is only allowed to do basic arithmetic, so I can get away with just the coercions & math symbols.

Answer (score 1):

A little more poking and this worked for all my use cases:

```
class EmptyValue < Numeric
  def to_s; ''; end
  def to_str; ''; end
  def to_i; 0; end
  def to_int; 0; end
  def to_f; 0.0; end

  def +(other)
   case other
   when String
     to_s + other
   when Fixnum
     to_i + other
   when Float
     to_f + other
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: I will probably also need implementations of *, /, and -